# NoSuchElementException with existing key

Tags: scala, hashmap, nosuchelementexception

Building class:

```
class Building(val name: String, val skill: String, @volatile var workHours: Int) {

  var workers = new HashMap[Artisan, Int]()

  def doWork(worker: Artisan): Boolean = {
    ...
    workers.get(worker) match {
      case Some(i: Int) =>
        worker.cash += i
        true
      case None => false
    }
    ...
  }
```

Artisan class:

```
class Artisan(val skill: String, city: City) extends Player(skill, city) {
  var assignment = new Building("Empty", "", 0)

  def doWork() {
    if ( !assignment.doWork(this) )
    ...
  }

  def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean = other.isInstanceOf[Artisan]

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: Artisan =>
      (that canEqual this) &&
        assignment == that.assignment &&
        skill == that.skill
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode(): Int = {
    val state = Seq(assignment, skill)
    state.map(_.hashCode()).foldLeft(0)((a, b) => 31 * a + b)
  }
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test
def testIncome() {
  val building = new Building("Bakery", "Builder", 10)
  building.setSallery(100, player)  // add player to building hashmap
  player.assignment = building
  player.doWork()
  assertEquals("Should earn 100", player.cash, 100)
}
```

output:

```
Negative test case
```

I do not see how this code could actually provide this error. When my code should just return false if the element does not exists. By debugging the program the Artisan object is added to my hashmap, so I do not understand why it would fail.

Comment: What does your `Artisan` class look like? You're using `equals` to see if the worker key is in the set but the `apply` method is using `==`, which just calls `equals` though if you override it, it can cause issues.

Comment: You can use the `contains` method to check if a `Map` contains a key, i.e. `!workers.contains(worker)`.

Comment: I have another test case using `keySet.exists(_.equals(worker)))`. Wouldn't that give the same result?

Comment: As @Noah says, it would be interesting to look at your `Artisan` class. To me this looks like a mismatch between your `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: I see that `Artisan` class has vars inside. Not sure how much sense makes using such class as a key (and why is that even possible). In theory, methods like `doWork` should return new object, rather than modify an existing one, etc.

Comment: Only using val inside my hashCode() in Artisan class did the trick. Thank you guys so much for this valuable lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` isn't encouraged in Scala. Your error message looks as if the whole function gets evaluated, even though there was a return statement. There are a couple of alternatives for `return` in case like yours:

1) using Option

```
var workers = new HashMap[Artisan, Int]()

  def doWork(worker: Artisan): Boolean = {
    val maybeIncome = workers.get(worker)
    maybeIncome match {
        case None => false
        case Some(income) => {
          val result = <do something with income that returns Boolean>
          result
         }
       }
    }
```

2) using for-comprehensions

```
var workers = new HashMap[Artisan, Int]()

  def doWork(worker: Artisan): Boolean = {
    val result = for { income <- workers.get(worker) } yield {
      <do something with income that returns boolean>
    }
    result getOrElse false
  }
```

UPDATE: I see that your Artisan class has mutable elements in it. Using such class as a key might give unpredictable results (and I wonder why is it even possible). I would rather define two maps: Map[ArtisanID, Artisan] and Map[ArtisanID, income], both of which would have immutable keys. (ArtisanID can be anything that uniquely identifies your Artisan and never changes).

Comment: Even though this was a great respond to my null pointing error, it  did not help solve my understanding. Now .get(worker) results to None, even when debugging the program shows that the element is placed within the hashmap as intended.

Comment: That is really strange. The semantics of `get` is that it returns `None` when the key isn't present and `Some(value)`, when the key is present. How does your `Artisan` class look? or, better yet, could you show some of the calling code that uses `doWork`?

Comment: The other thing: your `workers` is a `var`. May be you should try using mutable Map instead? Apart from that, could you print out all `workers` keys at the entry into your `doWork` function? That might shed some light.

Comment: Ouch, you are using class with mutable elements as a key. That's asking for trouble. Can you design a key which would be not mutable?

Comment: I will try to edit my variables used to hashkey and only used vals instead. I will update the code again when I'm done.